# how to excute a simple query use sqlapi++ with oracle

Tags: c++, oracle, ora-00932

here is the code:

cmd1.setCommandText("select * from lp.human_tb_meta_sex");
 cmd1.Execute();

while (cmd1.FetchNext())
 {
  SAString sas=cmd1.Field("id").asString();
  cout<<"sas id:"<

it gave me ORA-00932 error...I dont know why..?

Comment: Is lp.human_tb_meta_sex a table, view or what ?
I suspect a view and there is an invalid expression in the view.
Can you do the select from sql*plus ?

Comment: lp.human_tb_meta_sex a table is a table,and I can do the query in sql*plus,any ideas?
I found that this error occurs when the primary key in the table is Number,I change the type to Varchar2,the error gones...But I need the primary key be Number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably "id" is the primary key.

If it is defined as a NUMBER in the database, that could include fractions (eg 3.5).

If you define it as NUMBER(10,0) then it will always be an integer.

Since you are trying to pull it out as a String [.asString()] there could be a conversion issue.